# Copy cell inot another sheet and Autofill the copied cell 10 times

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy the cell contents in C10  from one sheet (called "New Customers") to another sheet's (called "Inventory") next available row.

Once the cell is copied, it should be copied or autofilled down 10 times. So 10 rows in the Inventory sheet have the same Customer ID populated.

Note: This macro will be ran multiple times and it should always populate the "Inventory" sheet with whatever the next avaiblaable 10 rows are at that point.
I have not figured out the Autofill part. That's where I need your help, the rest does what it should. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
Sub copyCustomer()
'copy customer ID into inventory sheet. Then autofill inventory 10 times.
'need for this to OFFSET to add a new customer next time macro is ran. 
    Set Source = Sheets("New Customers")
    Sheets("New Customers").Select
    Range("C10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Inventory").Select
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
   'Autofill this 10 times
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (which replaces all your present code)

```
Sub copyCustomer()
    Sheets("New Customers").Range("C10").Copy Sheets("Inventory").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(10)
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant! Yes, that worked perfectly fine. Thank you @SJR